# Data integrity and privacy

Tags: privacy, anonymity

I have a crowd sensing system where user after checking the task I provide for a location x, sends temperature values to the contract of that location.

I've been trying to a way to implement data integrity and privacy however, so far with no luck.

I'd like ensure the integrity of the data sent in the sense that the user is actually in that location and not just faking the location or values to get a reward, second issue is when the user sends a completed task we could know that he should have been in the location x which is a privacy concern for the user. In-other words can I ensure location privacy in the sense that location is always kept private.

Any ideas on how to implement this, or documents I could read to assist.

Comment: I don't know all your requirements, but instead of making the location data private, can't you try to make the user anonymous?

Comment: Tried to think of a way to implement this using ring signatures. However, wasnt valid in our scenario. Any recommendations of how can we make user anonymous?

Comment: I was meaning to use anonymous ethereum addresses. If that user is in the location, then he can use any address to send the verification data to the contract. Who owns that address can be known only to the user who sent it. I don't know if this fits into your problem. If it works, that solves privacy.

Comment: That would work yes. However, an anonymous address would be using Monero? Could you tell me how to implement such a system or anonymous addresses.

Comment: Every ethereum address is in fact anonymous until the owner reveals that this address belongs to him/her

Comment: Yes I understand. However, in our case once data is being submitted from a certain account thus we'll be able to link this account to the address.

Comment: Could you further elaborate on your approach and how to implement it, so that I could further envision it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95615/discussion-between-sanjay-s-b-and-user51821).

Comment: Okay perfect, waiting for you.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like ensure the integrity of the data sent in the sense that the user is actually in that location and not just faking the location

This is outright impossible. You need to trust the data coming from the client. Unless you have a "validator" that stands next to the device and checks the user is not spoofing GPS coordinates this is not possible.

> Second issue is when the user sends a completed task we could know that he should have been in the location x which is a privacy concern for the user. In-other words can I ensure location privacy in the sense that location is always kept private.

Easiest solution would be having this data offchain and not apply a blockchain for this problem.